# how to translate special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a column in my data whose name is like following
`" [90][Cont1mA_TEST_UP_2] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-100][-40 "`

I don't know how to read these blank spaces, square brackets etc

```
" &#9190&#93&#32&#91Cont1mA_TEST_UP_2&#93&#32&#91mV&#93&#32&#91N&#47A&#93&#32&#91N&#47A&#93&#32&#91&#45100&#93&#32&#91&#4540&#93 "
```

I've tried replacing all the special characters with their respective ASCII's

```
//console.log(dataFile.[90][Cont1mA_TEST_UP_2] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-100][-40])
//console.log(dataFile.&#9190&#93&#32&#91Cont1mA_TEST_UP_2&#93&#32&#91mV&#93&#32&#91N&#47A&#93&#32&#91N&#47A&#93&#32&#91&#45100&#93&#32&#91&#4540&#93)
```

I need the respective values to make a Scatter Plot graph and this value gives me the color shades as if certain threshold color will be changed accordingly

[image: ScatterPlot]

this image is just showing the X and Y points and green means pass, and red means fail. now i want my [90][con...][][][][][]etc column to change the color codes and according to certain threshold see my data (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dehya/Django_Public/master/INOVAdatasetforParametricWafer.csv)

When i check the data of my file it is shown like this on my console.

[image: console]

Comment: Welcome to SO @DehyaRao. Perhaps you would like to share with us why you need to encode the characters and share the JavaScript and HTML you have tried so far (not just the string).

Comment: Tests Executed,Test Time (ms),[3][Maintenance Counter] [m] [N/A][N/A][-500][11500],[11][Cont120uA_RESET_N] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[12][Cont120uA_I2C_SD] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200]

Comment: the above is some what my CSV file and name of columns

Comment: i need to read the names of columns so that i can change the color code of my graph according to the threshold on any partivcular column

Answer (score 0):

From your link I see this

```js
let dataString = `Lot ID,Wafer_ID,Probe Count,Unit Number,X,Y,Head Number,Site Number,Die Pass/Fail,Hard Bin No,Hard Bin Name,Hard Bin Pass/Fail,Soft Bin No,Soft Bin Name,Soft Bin Pass/Fail,Tests Executed,Test Time (ms),[3][Maintenance Counter] [m] [N/A][N/A][-500][11500],[11][Cont120uA_RESET_N] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[12][Cont120uA_I2C_SD] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[13][Cont120uA_I2C_SCL] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[14][Cont120uA_I2S_SDATA] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[15][Cont120uA_I2S_MCLK] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[16][Cont120uA_I2S_FRCK] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[17][Cont120uA_I2S_BCK] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[18][Cont120uA_GPIO_1] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[19][Cont120uA_GPIO_0] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[20][Cont120uA_STATUS] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200],[21][Cont120uA_TEST_EN] [mV] [N/A][N/A][-1000][-200]`

const firstBracket = dataString.indexOf("[")
const header = dataString.substring(0, firstBracket)
const data = dataString.substring(firstBracket).split(",").join("\n").replace(/\] ?\[/g,"],[").replace(/[\[|\]]/g, '"')
console.log(data)
d3.csv.parse(data, function(error, data) { 
 // Do your scatter here 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: saw ur update but the thing is i have 450 parameters tb exact i need to write this for 450 seperatly?

Comment: I do not understand. My code will create the data you need from the string you posted. Only need to run it once